# How to create a pulse effect on an image for a couple seconds when the page loads?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a pulse effect on an image but it is not working so far. I have tried to a `span` element and it works like that:

HTML:

```
<span class="pulse"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.pulse {
  margin:100px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cca92c;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
.pulse:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}
```

I want to the same with this image:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="item">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cNjXna/guided_inv_icon.png" alt="">
</a>
```

When the page loads, the image should have a pulse effect or only get the image a bit bigger for 2 seconds in order to indicate interactivity and then the image should keep his original shape.

Any suggestions?

I have created this pen: https://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/ZyOJYM

**EDIT**

I need to create that same effect in the image below the yellow circle. The yellow circle made from the `span` is doing what I want to achieve with the image below.

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine. So what is wrong?

Comment: `.pulse:hover { animation: none; }` should be swapped with the `animation: pulse 2s infinite;` in the default. You want to animate during hover.

Comment: @Justinas the `span` is working fine. Not the image. I want to create in that image, the same as the yellow circle there.

Comment: Yes, @PatrickRoberts but I need to create that same effect in the image below the yellow circle. The yellow circle made from the `span` is doing what I want to achieve with the image below.

Comment: do you mean pulsate effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the same animation to the image, similar to how you applied the animation to the `span` element.

```
.item img{
animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
```

Check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/harisali90/pen/dRXzWG)

**EDIT**

For showing a bigger image for 2 seconds and then reducing it to normal size, I have added the `magnified` animation.

```
@keyframes magnified{
0%{
transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}
70%{
transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}
100%{
transform: scale(1,1);
}
}
```

And you can add multiple animations to the element:

```
.item img{
animation: pulse 2s infinite, magnified 2s 1;
}
```

I have updated the [pen](https://codepen.io/harisali90/pen/dRXzWG) to show these effects.

Comment: Add `infinite` instead of 1 here:  `item img{
  animation: pulse 2s infinite, magnified 2s infinite;
}` then it shows the exact pulse effect for the whole image.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below lines of code to perform pulsate animation effect using HTML and CSS3 : Here I have used keyframe property of css to perform animation effect.

```
<span class="pulse"></span>

<style>
.pulse {
  margin:100px;
  display: block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff8717;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}
.pulse:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204,169,44, 0);
  }
}


</style>
```